# Suggestion window in mdi form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi

I have a problem stated below....
I have a MDI form having different child form. if i open the form then if related data not exist in database, a suggestion banner should appear top of the forms to enter related data first. Even, if I close the child form, suggestion banner should remain open and Onclick on that banner go to specific form to add the record. There should be different banner of different forms. so please help me to implement this scenario.
Thanks in Advance.

I want to use which control as banner. so after struggling i fount panel best as banner. Setting panel property -> AccessibleRole = Alert. So I implement scenario easily.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening the child form, open the banner form first (which opens the child form).

Then check in the banner form if the data has been entered. If it has:- close the banner form.

Comment: I want to use which control as banner. so after struggling i fount panel best as banner. Setting panel property -> AccessibleRole = Alert. So I implement scenario easily.